# How to find what is using the CPU for indices pytorch / numpy : indices should be either on cpu or on the same device as the indexed tensor (cpu)

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to track down a fix to RuntimeError: indices should be either on cpu or on the same device as the indexed tensor (cpu)
so I can run an image diffusion model:
https://github.com/kakaobrain/karlo

Full error output here:
https://github.com/kakaobrain/karlo/issues/12

The error showed up when I explicitly set the gpu with
`os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="1"`

I've changed cpu to `"cuda"` or `cuda()` where `"cpu"` or `cpu()` was, but the error is still thrown when I try to run the model
(gradio started via  `python demo/product_demo.py --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8085  --root-dir .`)

Any suggestions of what I can explore to find out what is still using the cpu for indices?
Or is something else happening?

Comment: It seems `self.timestep_map` is on CPU, while `ts` is on GPU. Try tracing the execution with a debugger and confirm if what I said is true. If so, figure out which of your tensor corresponds to `self.timestep_map` and move it to GPU.

Comment: Thanks; I tried 

```timestep_map_tensor = th.tensor(timestep_map)
  cuda_device = th.device("cuda")
  timestep_map_tensor = timestep_map_tensor.to(cuda_device)```

but ran out of vram loading things (I have 24GB on the one card)

That may be a separate issue getting everything to fit

Comment: Was able to load things into VRAM using set 'PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF=max_split_size_mb:512' and even starting seeing an image generating :) but ran out of VRAM on generating; progress :)

Comment: lowering the "maximum batch size" I am able to successfully run things :)
after those two changes

Comment: Glad you solved it! Consider posting your comments as an answer then accept it to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

implemented

```
timestep_map_tensor = th.tensor(timestep_map)   
cuda_device = th.device("cuda")   
timestep_map_tensor = timestep_map_tensor.to(cuda_device)
```

but ran out of vram loading things (I have 24GB on the one card).

Was able to load things into VRAM using set

`'PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF=max_split_size_mb:512'`

and even starting seeing an image generating :) but ran out of VRAM on generating.

lowering the "maximum batch size" I am able to successfully run things :) after those two changes